# resigning and skipping training

Tags: resignation, training

I received a job offer from a company (Fortune 500) a few months ago. Almost 4 months later, I'm starting to dislike it because there isn't much learning for me, and to be honest, it's not the career path I want to take. I feel very demotivated "working" here.

I've already received another job offer from a smaller company and need to join by 25th June. I only need to provide a week notice to this company (no contract or anything) because I'm still on my probation period. The problem is they are sending me abroad for training next week (with another guy, but the training is mainly for me) and have already booked and arranged my ticket/visa. It obviously looks bad if I resign right after my training, even though I would get a certificate for it, would look good on the CV, etc.

I want to resign immediately, before the trip, for this very reason but I am not sure how to approach HR. Should I just tell them to cancel my trip and I will work at the office for a week instead of going abroad? Deferring my other job by like a couple of months isn't really possible.

Comment: You might want to check whether you signed anything that says you need to pay them back for the training if you don't stay for at least X months or years afterwards. This might apply even if you tell them now (but then they'd presumably *have* to send you).

Comment: Already checked. No such thing in the offer letter which I signed. Only need to provide a week notice before resigning.

Answer (score 6):

If you have not any problems to live a couple of weeks without being paid, I'd suggest to resign immediately and then arrange with the HR what to do of your notice period: since you are still in probation, they can let you go immediately without requesting it (or if you are lucky they will pay it even if you don't work).

As for the trip, this will be a problem of the HR or who is in charge of this, but from your side you do all what you should resigning as soon as possible to let the company handle this with as many time as you can "offer", which is the right thing to do.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78471/discussion-on-answer-by-gianluca-resigning-and-skipping-training).

Answer (score 2):

Personal ethics aside and with your best interest in mind, let´s look at the Pros and cons of resigning early.

**Pro:**

- You may make a more favorable professional impression.
- You may save your employer some money.
- You´ll probably have some (unpaid?) holidays.
- You may sleep better because you have the moral high ground.

**Con:**

- You will probably loose some money.
- You won´t get the training-certificate.
- You may make a less favorable professional impression (who throws away a free training?)
- You may sleep worse, because you missed out on something.

---

Let me say a word about the ethics part. While I´m all for more ethics in the workplace, it´s not a inherent feature of capitalistic markets and it leads to an unbalanced situation if only one player adheres to it. The general rule is to look after maximizing your potential, and let others look after maximizing theirs.

In this case:

1. Your employer decided to enter into a risk by taking you on.
2. Your employer decided it would be best to have a probation period with a short notice time.
3. Your employer decided to put you through extensive training.
4. Your employer decided not to instate any penalty for thanking a "free ride" on the training and quitting right after.
5. Your employer controls every aspect of the work space that demotivated and ultimately lead to your resigantion.

They did this, not because it was a ethical choice, not because they wanted to be nice, but because they though they could maximize their profits this way.

Now, we a re talking about a fortune 500 company. You won´t create a mess in their financials. You wont risk them to go bust because they had to rely on your talent. At best you put the bonus of the responsible HR-person at risk ...

I am not saying you should not follow your personal ethical compass - just don´t think for a minute that your employer would do the same for you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends on how important the training is for you. If it is not important, then just quit before it and let them figure it out.

If it is, the compromise is if you tell them that you want to quit before the training but you still want to do the training and you are ready to cover the cost of it as you would be leaving their company right after.

Might be costly, but you will still get the certificate and keep your professional integrity. They might even let you get the training for a fraction of the actual cost.